# Images not showing up in correct spot

Tags: html, css

I have 4 social media icons that I put on my page but they're either being hid by other divs even though they have a larger z-index value or they show below the top div. I want them to be to the right of the church image I can play around with the code and get them to show up but they are appearing below my top section. I've tried every way possible to add the code here but I can't figure out how to do it so I'll link to the site.

site at http://www.joekellywebdesign.com/churchsample1/index.html

stylesheet at 
http://www.joekellywebdesign.com/churchsample1/css/styles.css

the style I have defined for the div is:

```
socialmediaicons {
    margin:50px 50px 0 0; 
    float:right; 
    z-index:90;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I don't see it under the top section. Can you make it do that again so I can see what you're talking about. Should help me help you!

Comment: They are there now. When I use position:absolute I don't see them so I assume they are being hid by other divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the float declaration, and add

```
top:0;
right:0;
```